# How to sort the dropdown using Bootstrap Tagsinput?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using bootstrap tagsinput to display some values, but I'm not being able to order them once the user start searching.
It's showing the values ascending, but I need it descending.

I didn't find any method or any way to sort it there.

Is it possible to sort using tagsinput?

Answer (score 0):

The below will sort the tags input once an item is added. The HTML element sorting code is taken from [Link](https://j11y.io/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/). `OnItemAdded` event will sort the relevant spans. You can update the relevant code to sort based on user searching.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#name').tagsinput({
    tagClass: 'label label-default label-slow',
    trimValue: true,
    allowDuplicates: true,
    freeInput: true
  });

  $('input').on('itemAdded', function () {
    $('.bootstrap-tagsinput > span').sortElements(function (a, b) {
      return $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
    });
  });
});

/**
 * jQuery.fn.sortElements
 * --------------
 * @param Function comparator:
 *   Exactly the same behaviour as [1,2,3].sort(comparator)
 *   
 * @param Function getSortable
 *   A function that should return the element that is
 *   to be sorted. The comparator will run on the
 *   current collection, but you may want the actual
 *   resulting sort to occur on a parent or another
 *   associated element.
 *   
 *   E.g. $('td').sortElements(comparator, function(){
 *      return this.parentNode; 
 *   })
 *   
 *   The <td>'s parent (<tr>) will be sorted instead
 *   of the <td> itself.
 */
    jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function () {
      var sort = [].sort;
      return function (comparator, getSortable) {
        getSortable = getSortable || function () { return this; };
        var placements = this.map(function () {
          var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
            parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,
            // Since the element itself will change position, we have
            // to have some way of storing its original position in
            // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
            nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
              document.createTextNode(''),
              sortElement.nextSibling
            );
          return function () {
            if (parentNode === this) {
              throw new Error(
                "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
              );
            }
            // Insert before flag:
            parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
            // Remove flag:
            parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);
          };
        });

        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function (i) {
          placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });
      };
    })();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px; }
  .bootstrap-tagsinput input {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: inherit; }
    .bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
      border: none;
      box-shadow: none; }
  .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: white; }
    .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
      margin-left: 8px;
      cursor: pointer; }
      .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
        content: "x";
        padding: 0px 2px; }
      .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
        .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); }
  .bootstrap-tagsinput .icon-white {
    margin-left: 5px; }
</style>

<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
```